# Compilable analog of Nearest?

Tags: compile, nearest

Is there any analog of `Nearest` that is compilable?

```
compnearest = 
 Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}, x}, Nearest[list, x], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
compnearest[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4]
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[compnearest]


        2 arguments         1 Real register         2 Tensor registers      Underflow checking off      Overflow checking off       Integer overflow checking off       RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R1)0 = A1         R0 = A2         Result = T(R1)1

1   T(R1)1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Nearest][ T(R1)0, R0]] 2    Return
```

My attempt is the following:

```
nearestNeighbor1 = 
  Compile[{{point, _Real, 1}, {data, _Real, 2}}, 
   Module[{closestIndex, minDistance, distance},
    closestIndex = 1;
    minDistance = Total[(point - Compile`GetElement[data, 1])^2];
    Do[
     distance = Total[(point - Compile`GetElement[data, i])^2];
     If[distance < minDistance,
      minDistance = distance;
      closestIndex = i;]
     , {i, Length[data]}];
    closestIndex], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True];
pt = {0.1, 0.3};
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000000, 2}];
nearestNeighbor1[pt, data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

I feel that it may be made much more efficient: `Nearest` is at least an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184329/46569

Comment: `Nearest` is already "compiled", so no point to compile it again. It's speed-up comes mostly from employing a _Bounding Volume Hierarchy (BVH)_, as special kind of search tree for spatial problems. There is just no chance that your brute-force approach (on a CPU) will beat it.

Comment: So, as Goofy pointed out: Do not even attempt to do that; instead use `LibraryLink` and `LTemplate` to link one of the well-developed bounding volume hierarchies out there. FYI, working with this kind of trees was the reason why I swtiched to using C++ more broadly. Often you want to hold the BVH as long as possible and make queries of various types to it. That does simply not go well with `Compile` as the latter is just not _meant_ for such things.